# Inline css is not working in my pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have used tcpdf in codeignter.I want to give inline css for td.

Mycode is:

```
 <table style="float:left;width:100%; border:1px solid #c2c2c2; margin-top:10px;">
    <tr style="float:left;width:100%;">
        <td style="float:left;width:50%;">
            <tr style="float:left;width:260px;">
                <th style="float:left;width:20px;color:#2F70A8;"><span style="border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;">Sr no</span></th>
                <thstyle="float:left;width:80px;color:#2F70A8;"><span style="border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;">Date</span></th>
                <th style="float:left;width:80px;color:#2F70A8;"><span style="border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;">Credit Amount</span></th>
                <th style="float:left;width:80px;color:#2F70A8;"><span style="border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;">Description</span></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $i = 1;
                foreach($br_result as $branch)
                {
            ?>
                    <tr style="float:left;">
                        <td style="float:left;width:20px;"><span style="float:left;border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;"><?php echo $i; ?></span></td>
                        <td style="float:left;width:80px;"><span style="float:left;border:1px solid #c2c2c2;"><?php echo $branch->Date; ?></span></td>
                        <td style="float:left;width:80px;"><span style="float:left;border:1px solid #c2c2c2;"><?php echo $branch->payment; ?></span></td>
                        <td style="float:left;width:80px;"><span style="float:left;border:1px solid #c2c2c2;"><?php echo $branch->remark; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
                $i++;
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here span css as **border-right** and **border** are not working. I have also try some other method like give class to my span and created  and apply css but it is not working. So what should  I have to try to solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF doesnot support all the css properties, you can use CSS for some basic formatting. But i dont think TCPDF supports the border css properties.

**[Documentation TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php)**

Alternatives for this

- **[wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)**
- **[DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)**
- **[mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)**

Comment: so is there any solution to give css like this?

Comment: I have apply border to another table so it works but here it is not woking.

Answer (score 1):

As `<span>` is inline element, try adding style to span `display:inline-block;` or `display:block;` which ever suits your design.

```
<span style="display:inline-block; border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;">
```